# ID an electronic part believed to be a varistor

Tags: identification, components

[image: Hello I am trying to ID this electronic part]

This is a part to a Sony TV motherboard.
I have no idea but I believe it's a varistor for power surges on the main board.
I'm trying to find a replacement part.
Any help to ID the component will be appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image][image]

Comment: That package isn't super common for varistors from a quick Google. What makes you think it is one?

Comment: Truly, I had no idea what it really was.

Comment: why do you think that it needs replacement?

Comment: Video from Sony TV failed, Unit was producing a 6 Blink code... when I dismantled the TV the component was off the motherboard, resoldered it.. video restored but failed once again approx 3 mins later... my best guess is that component failing.

Comment: As the posted answer suggests it's likely an inductor. Based on the shape and the common sizing of 220. Is there no Lnnnn marking near it? Or under it? It could be the L9000 in the repair guide you show. Is there no schematic available? Can you make a schematic from what the part is connected to? Likely just a V+ and the output from an IC.

Comment: But truth be told, a part falling off the board is a symptom not the root cause. Of either bad solder or something went bad enough to heat the board up enough for the part to desolder and fall off from gravity. I'd expect other parts to also be half soldered or cooked. The capacitor might have leaked from underneath. Etc.

Comment: If the inductor in that DC converter got so hot it melted its own solder you probably had a short somewhere after the inductor.  Do you measure a short to ground on that power rail?  Is there a blown up cap somewhere nearby?

Comment: Are any of those aluminum electrolytics (the silver cans) bulged up at the top? The top should be flat as a pancake.

Comment: No not that I can see.. I'll post a few more pics of the board.. not seeing any damage as such.. except the inductor position.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing an inductor similar to this...
https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/SRR1260.pdf

What is the DC resistance?  Should be well under 1 ohm.  Likely 22 uH.

Comment: That part you link to has a different package shape, but I also believe it's likely to be an inductor of some varying quality.

Comment: Yes, it's an inductor.  I recognize it.